# How to upload a file with AngularJS and save it with ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I am using a directive for AngularJS called angular-file-upload. I have set it up and the image upload works fine, however I can't seem to parse the file to the server side (express js).

Jade:

```
input.form-input(ng-model="userAvatarFile" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" name="userAvatarFile" type="file")
```

This is the code for AngularJS:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {

    console.log($files);

    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
        var file = $files[i];
        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: '/api/user/upload', 
            method: 'POST',
            data: {myObj: $scope.userAvatarFile},
            file: file, 
        }).progress(function(evt) {
            console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
};
```

And express:

```
exports.upload = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files);
};
```

The console always prints out the following for express:

```
 {}
 undefined
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: upload() function is an Async .. you can use it inside the loop like this , you have send all file in the array and save.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to say, can you reword it?

Answer (score 1):

Multipart middleware was removed in [Connect 3.0](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0#backwards-compatibility-changes). Connect recommends either [`connect-multiparty`](https://github.com/superjoe30/connect-multiparty) or [`connect-busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy). IMHO `connect-busboy` is better, so here's how to do it:

(Of course, run `npm install --save connect-busboy`)

```
// Main file, stays the same for all the other examples
var express = require('express'),
    busboy  = require('connect-busboy');

app.use(busboy({ immediate: true }));
```

---

```
// Route file
exports.upload = function (req, res) {
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        // fieldname will be 'file', file will be... um... the file (in binary encoding), filename will be the file's name
    });
    req.busboy.on('field', function (key, value) {
        // key will be 'myObj', value will be $scope.userAvatarFile
    });
};
```

If you want to save the image to a file, you can do this:

```
exports.upload = function (req, res) {
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        // saveTo is the temporary path
        var saveTo = path.join(os.tmpDir(), path.basename(fieldname));
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));

        // Do stuff with saveTo
    });
};
```

However, this is a security risk (saving to the disk, which is why req.files does not exist anymore), so most(?) libraries that work with files (e.g. Cloudinary) provide a WriteStream (or something that looks and feels like one). Here's how it works with Cloudinary:

```
exports.upload = function (req, res) {
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        var stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(function(result) { console.log(result); });

        // You should have been able to do file.pipe(stream), but Cloudinary's stream isn't a real WriteStream, but just an object with two functions. Well, the following works too:

        file.on('data', stream.write);
        file.on('end', stream.end);
    });
};
```

FWIW, I copied your code and tested it and it works just fine. Let me know if you've got any problems. I had the same issue a week ago, so I got to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

[tgkokk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674791/tgkokk) example using Cloudinary no longer works with Cloudinary v1.1.1. Cloudinary updated the upload_stream method to return a Transform stream object.  So use 'pipe' instead of manually adding events to on('data') and on('end').

https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm#version-11-upload_stream-change-notes

```
exports.upload = function (req, res) {
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        var stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(function(result) {    console.log(result); 
        });

        // pipe can be used now
        file.pipe(stream);
    });
};
```